# Add new page button missing from site actions dropdown

Tags: 2013, publishing

Until today, the content creator for my company's intranet would use the add new page button in the gear button drop down to create new pages.

Today that button disappeared and none of us had changed any settings on the site. Also, it became impossible to add new pages to the page library.

After turning the site publishing feature off then back on, I can now create new pages for the pages library, but am unable to change the page layout. Also, the add new page button is still missing.

This is a completely new issue for me and I am wondering if anyone has any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your Page layouts and Site templates information under Site Settings > Look and Feel (your site url + /_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx) and see what layouts are available to be used in the site.

Also, check to see if the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated at the site collection.

Does your ribbon look like this: (can you take a screen shot of what you're seeing?)
[image]
[image]

Comment: The SP Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated.

Also, there are several page layouts available.

This issue appeared today and no one has made any modifications to any settings on the farm.

Comment: Is this a 2010 site or a 2013 site?  The question is tagged 2013 but you refer to the Site Actions dropdown which doesn't exist in 2013. Are you talking about the gear icon?  I'm only asking because what you describe is similar to what our users noticed after we upgraded to 2013 from 2010. It almost sounds like the page is no longer a publishing page

Comment: I thought the gear icon was the site actions menu?

Anyways, its 2013. I am referring to the gear icon.

Comment: You mentioned you couldn't edit the page layout but you could now add a new page. Can you edit the page layout for the new page that you add?

Comment: Nope. The ribbon has less options than it did before. They arent greyed out either. They have been removed.

Comment: Scratch that. I turned the site publishing feature off then on again and I can now see those options in the ribbon.

The add a page and add a site options are still missing though.

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes that is what the ribbon looked like. Recycling the publishing site feature corrected that issue.

However, the buttons are still missing from the gear/site actions menu.

Comment: Can you add a site from Site Contents from the gear icon?  That is where it is for us now.  I'm not sure if you have done customizations but Add a Site isn't in the ribbon for us.

Comment: I dont manage content, apparently that option was there. And no customizations were done to the ribbon or site actions/gear menu. And like I said, this started today by itself.

Comment: I am only able to see edit page, add and app and site contents (in that particular section of the site actions menu)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39248/discussion-between-sween-sp-and-john-s).